# CORS issue POST request (403 Forbidden) of App Android generated with Sencha CMD 6.5

Tags: android, tomcat, post, extjs, cors

I am trying to generated a app Android (Front-end) with Sencha CMD 6.5 that send requests to Tomcat Server (Back-end).

The problem is the POST method , when App send the request in the header the "Origin" parameter is set to "file://" and the CORS of tomcat reject the request (Forbidden 403).

HEADER

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.9
Connection: keep-aliv(e)
Content-Length: 39
Host: 192.168.1.91: 8080
Origin: file: //
Referer: -
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0(Linux;Android7.0;MI5Build/NRD90M;wv)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Version/4.0Chrome/64.0.3282.137MobileSafari/537.36
```

FILTER defined on tomcat 8.0 in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Cache-Control,Content-Language,Expires,Last-Modified,Pragma,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
      <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

The funny thing is that with the GET method not set anything in the Origin parameter and the Tomcat CORS accepts it.

There are only two solutions:

1. Set the parameter Origin of header (I did not find anything in any forum, like this, like senchaforum, etc.)
2. Modify CORS Filter of TOMCAT 8. (I did not find anything in any forum, like this, like senchaforum, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is use ContainerResponseFilter, instead of filter of tomcat.

```
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

@Provider
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext creq, ContainerResponseContext cres) {

    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = cres.getHeaders();
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control,Content-Language,Expires,Last-Modified,Pragma,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT");
    //headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "10");
    }

}
```

I already tried this, in case someone thinks it would have worked with original filter:

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Welcome guys, I hope it help someone in the future.

Daniel